# Switching fragments: should I add some action?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have two fragments `FirstFragment()` and `SecondFragment()` and a frame `R.id.frame`.
In my code, I need to switch often between `FirstFragment()` and `SecondFragment()` inside the frame `R.id.frame`. To do that, I use the following code.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.frame, new SecondFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

According to the best practices, is this code enough? Or should I add some other action? For example, **destroy the old fragment**, delete it or what.

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` = `remove(FirstFragment)` + `add(SecondFragment)`

As soon as first fragment is removed, it will be eligible for garbage collection. No extra actions required from developer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using show and hide after adding your fragments. This will not re-create your fragments everytime you switch between fragments.

```
private void addFragment(Fragment fragment, Class<? extends Fragment> tag) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.content, fragment, tag.getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(tag.getName()
        ).commit();
    }
private void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment == null) {
            return;
        }
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.show(fragment).commit();
    }

private void hideFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment == null) {
            return;
        }
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.hide(fragment).commit();
    }
```